# dpkg error while trying to extract a file

Tags: dpkg

I am getting an error while trying to extract a package and I have no idea why this is happening Is the data corrupted ?

```
sudo dpkg -x ti-openmpacc_1.1.1_cortexa15hf-vfp-neon.ipk /evmk2h_nfs/

dpkg-deb: error: archive 'ti-openmpacc_1.1.1_cortexa15hf-vfp-neon.ipk' has premature member 'data.tar.gz' before 'control.tar', giving up
```

Can anyone help plz :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be an ar file, so you should be able to extract it with:`ar x ti-openmpacc_1.1.1_cortexa15hf-vfp-neon.ipk`

The archives within the ar archive, should be tar, so you can extract those with `tar -zxf`.

References:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man5/deb.5.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369127/extracting-and-creating-ipk-files